# Autoscroll a ListView?

Tags: java, android, concurrency, android-listview

I've implemented a ListView for reading an rss feed and I would like to implement an autoscroll for this list view.

I've probably to use something like:

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(???);
            }
        });
```

but how to read smoothly all the position and then start from the top again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could simply iterate through the elements in the list view by using some sort of counter:

```
int count = listView.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(i);
        }
    }); 
}
// Once the method gets to here, i == count and we're at the last position
// So you can use some logic to scroll back to the top e.g. 
// listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
```

Instead of using `post()`, you may want to think about using a `Timer` object instead, as I believe there isn't much control about when runnable's on the post queue are executed.

**EDIT**

So I managed to get a rudimentary, but working, example by using a `Timer` with a fixed-rate scheduled `ScrollTimerTask`

```
//This is an inner class, with i an int in the Activity, starting at 0;
public class ScrollTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (i < getListView().getCount()) {
            getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(i);
            i++;
        }
        else {
            getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            i == 0;
        }
}
```

Then, where you want to start moving down the list call `new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScrollTimerTask(), 0, 1000);`. This will start scrolling after no delay, and will schedule the scrolling task every 1000ms.

Note this is rudimentary and will crash the Activity when you close it, and runs continuously. To prevent the crash, I'd recommend keeping a reference to the `Timer` object and calling `Timer.cancel()` in the Activity's onPause() method. But it is a starting block!

Comment: This will not compile, the i has to be inside the Runnable class. And, I've already thought about something like this but I'm not sure how to pause the for. When I tried with something like Thread.sleep(1000) everything will block..

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly how I finally managed to do this, but I didn't know about the crash (in fact my activity is crashing on the change of orientatio). +1 for this!

Answer (score 0):

Add a big footer/header and jump when you reached the end to the beginning (0) and restart scrolling.

Comment: My problem actually is how to iterate through the elements, pause the thread and then restart. Can you provide me a snippet? (I didn't get your answer..)

Comment: You can only add a footer/header before you set your adapter. I'm not sure how slow that function scrolls but you could add every second a small count of elements check it yourself, and try to Tiger out if the end is visible with a call on the listview (forgot the function name)